# How can I convert one value from DB to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I saved ONE or MORE THAN ONE values from multiply select option to one value in DB. 
for example:" **Name1, Name2, Name3** "

When I leave from page and then return to page I need load and preselected these values to multiply select option.

I need this :

```
$("#form_meno").val([**"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"**]);
```

But I dont know how I convert it.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: long story made short. do not store multiple values in the same table cell... that's the reason why you won't find a function to cover your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` after removing the whitespaces using `replace()`

```js
let str = " Name1, Name2, Name3 ";
let arr = str.replace(/\s+/g,'').split(',');
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Depend on how you save these values but you can use `str.trim().split(', ') ` as well